Laplace's Approximation for Integral from 0 to Infinity
Background
I am working on a problem where I need to evaluate an integral from 0 to infinity and compare the numerical solution to an analytical approximation using Laplace's method. However, I am observing a significant discrepancy between the two solutions, and I am looking for insights or corrections to my approach.
Function and Integral
The function I am integrating is defined as:
$$f(r_s) = \lambda y_s \rho_s x r_s^{-4} - 0.5 \lambda \rho_s^2 x^2 r_s^{-8} - \lambda^2 r_s$$
where $ \lambda, y_s, \rho_s, $ and $ x $ are constants ($\lambda$ is small). The integral I am evaluating is:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{1}{\lambda} f(r_s)} \, dr_s$$
Derivation of $ r_s^* $ and Second Derivative
To apply Laplace's approximation, I first find the point $ r_s^* $ where $ f(r_s) $ is maximized. This is given by solving:
$$\frac{df}{dr_s} = 0$$
The second derivative at $ r_s^* $, $ f''(r_s^*) $, is used to approximate the integral around $ r_s^* $ using a Gaussian integral. The analytical result is then given by:
$$\sqrt{\frac{2\pi \lambda}{|f''(r_s^*)|}} e^{\frac{1}{\lambda} f(r_s^*)}$$
However, considering the bounds from 0 to infinity, I included a correction factor using the Q-function:
$$\text{Correction Factor} = 1 - Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{|f''(r_s^*)|}{\lambda}} r_s^*\right)$$
Numerical Solution
I used MATLAB's integral function with high precision settings to compute the integral numerically.
Issue
There is a significant gap between the numerical result and the analytical approximation. I suspect there might be an issue with the assumptions of the Gaussian approximation or the implementation of the correction factor.
Question
Could anyone provide insights into potential issues with my application of Laplace's approximation in this scenario? Are there better ways to handle the infinite bounds or corrections to my current approach?
Thank you for your help!

Why does $\lambda$ occur in so many places? You could normally cross it out and leave only a single factor $\lambda$ in the linear term of $f.$

@Lieven Since I wanna use Laplace Approximation and I need a large coefficient like $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

I am not sure about the validity of Laplace's method when the function $f$ is a different one (with a different local maximum) for every value of the large constant $1/\lambda$ in front of it.

@Lieven what is the properties of function $f$ in Laplace's Method?

As far as I understood the method it considers the limit of the integral of $\sqrt{M}\exp(Mf)$ for $M\to\infty$ where $f$ is a function that does not change with $M.$

Your integral has the form
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a{t^8}+\frac b{t^4}-\lambda t}dt=\frac1\lambda+o\Big(\frac1\lambda\Big),,\text{at},,\lambda\to 0$$

@Svyatoslav How? thank you.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a{t^8}+\frac b{t^4}-\lambda t}dt=\int_0^{\lambda^{\frac14}} e^{- ax^8+ bx^4-\frac\lambda x}\frac{dx}{x^2}+\int_{\lambda^{\frac14}}^\infty e^{-ax^8+ bx^4-\frac\lambda x}\frac{dx}{x^2}=I_1+I_2$$
$$I_2<\int_{\lambda^{\frac14}}^\infty e^{-ax^8+ bx^4}\frac{dx}{x^2}<\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^8+ bx^4}dx=\frac{C(a,b)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

$$e^{-a\lambda^2}\int_0^{\lambda^{\frac14}} e^{-\frac\lambda x}\frac{dx}{x^2}<I_1<e^{b\lambda}\int_0^{\lambda^{\frac14}} e^{-\frac\lambda x}\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
$$e^{-a\lambda^2}\int_{\lambda^{-\frac14}}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}dt<I_1<e^{b\lambda}\int_{\lambda^{-\frac14}}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}dt,\Rightarrow,I_1=\frac1\lambda+o\Big(\frac1\lambda\Big)$$
